# Handling XML Attribute in dynamically in PostgreSQL

Tags: xml, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I need to read attributes from an XML. Below is a sample xml

```
<users userid="79132e61-df0a-4af5-95db-92d8bb492c84" username="test" birthdate="2000-03-10" nationality="USA"/>
```

I am using below code to read attributes from this XML.

```
with cte (xmlcontent) as 
(

select '<users userid="79132e61-df0a-4af5-95db-92d8bb492c84" username="test" birthdate="2000-03-10" nationality="USA"/>'::xml )
select  Unnest(xpath('//@userid',XMLCONTENT))::text::uuid,
        Unnest(xpath('//@username',XMLCONTENT))::text,
        Unnest(xpath('//@nationality',XMLCONTENT))::text
from cte;
```

Problem is ,  `nationality` is not a mandatory attribute of this xml. My query produces no result when `nationality` doesn't exists in in XML.

How can I modify my query to handle this case?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I remove `nationality="USA"` from the XML, I still get one row with three columns, of the user id, "test", and an empty string.

Comment: are you using postgresql 9.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one solution which i found is to use **XMLEXISTS**.

below query working absolutely fine for me

```
with cte (xmlcontent) as 
    (
    
    select '<users userid="79132e61-df0a-4af5-95db-92d8bb492c84" username="test" birthdate="2000-03-10" nationality="USA"/>'::xml )
    select  Unnest(xpath('//@userid',XMLCONTENT))::text::uuid,
            Unnest(xpath('//@username',XMLCONTENT))::text,
            case when xmlexists('//@nationality' passing  XMLCONTENT) then Unnest(xpath('//@nationality',XMLCONTENT))::text else null end 
    from cte
```